# error reporting mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am converting a php script which contains mysql_* functions to PDO.

i want to dislay all the sql related errors in my old script but i noticed that wherever there is an **error in the sql syntax**, php will output a blank page even if error reporting is turned on. Also the error is not logged in the log file.

If i use mysql_error() function at the end of the script which contains multiple sql queries, then the errors reported by the individual sql queries will be **overwritten** and only the last created error will be displayed.

So my question is instead of using die() or mysql_error() functions at the end of each and every sql query, is there a way by which i can view all the errors in the script at once?

i am using PHP version 5.3.8 and mysql version 5.5.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @bažmegakapa : the question is not regarding error handling in PDO but abt the error handling in mysql_* functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is instead of using die() or mysql_error() functions at
>   the end of each and every sql query, is there a way by which i can
>   view all the errors in the script at once?

This is not recommended. Because instead of stopping the script (**usually at the critical point**) it would continue execution.

However if you really need this, you can keep all `SQL` errors in some container, for instance, like, `$errors` array. It would look like this (procedural code) :

```
<?php

$errors = array();

if ( ! mysql_query("SOME INVALID QUERY") ){

    array_push($errors, mysql_error());
}


if ( ! mysql_query("SOME ANOTHER INVALID QUERY") ){
   array_push( $errors, mysql_error() );
}

//lot of code
//.....

print_r( $errors );
```

`error_reporting` and `display_errors` they both have nothing to do with SQL errors, but PHP engine itself. They won't show any SQL error.

And also, as usual, stop using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: :Thanks a lot. exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Surely `mysql_error()` returns only error from the latest query.

About PHP returning a blank page, maybe you didn't turn the display_errors on. You need both `error_reporting` AND `display_errors` directives to be on in order to show errors.